# Datejs - Problem with 12:00 pm

Tags: javascript, date, datejs

I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.  I can't get Datejs to properly parse "12:00 pm" however, it seems to work fine on other dates.  Below is a clip from the Firefox debugger:

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome running in the console directly on the datejs website

Comment: Yeah, that worked for me too, actually

Comment: Which version of DateJS were you using in the above?

Comment: should also point out that "12:00 am" was incorrectly parsed to 12:00 instead of 00:00.

Comment: Silly aside: if you think about the literal meaning of "pm" there is no "12:00 pm" - though you can say "1200" in 24-hour format, or "noon"...

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/datejs/issues/detail?id=132

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Download the latest version of Datejs from SVN not the version in the "download" section.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the code in an IIFE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input type=text id=d onkeyup="parsedate()">
        </input>
        <br>
        <span id=output></span>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../static/js/date.js"></script>
        <script>
            ( function() {
                    parsedate = function() {
                        var input = document.getElementById('d').value;
                        var output = document.getElementById('output');
                        var d = Date.parse(input);
                        if (d !== null) {
                            output.innerHTML = d.toString();
                        } else {
                            output.innerHTML = "------"
                        }
                    }
                }());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The IIFE being

```
(function(){
    //code
}());
```

What I'm curious about is why FireFox behaves this way. I know they added security updates a few years back that prevent you from overwriting Date.prototype functions, but why is an IIFE capable of accessing this scope?